# Program blocks when calling ImageIO.read(file)

Tags: java, image, opengl, lwjgl, java-io

I'm trying to load textures for my lwjgl project with the built-in ImageIO.read(file) method.

Creating a new File object works, it's in the ImageIO.read() method that I have a problem.

```
public Texture(String fileName) {

System.out.println("Texture init called");

try {
    File img = new File("brick.png");
    System.out.println(img.exists()); //Returns true
    System.out.println(img.getAbsolutePath()); //Returns the correct path "/Users/griffinbabe/Documents/workspace/LWJGLTest/brick.png"
    System.out.println(img.canRead()); //Returns true
    Image im = ImageIO.read(img); //Blocks here, letting no printStackTrace, and letting the program running.
    System.out.println("Yes you did it!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is strange I never encountered the problem. If it can help, I'm running this on mac os Sierra and I'm using openGL.

Here is the main class, where the new Texture object is initialized.

```
public Window(int sizeX, int sizeY,Game game) {
    this.game = game;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("GLFW failed to initialize.");
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(sizeX,sizeY,"Game3Graphics",0,0);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    if (window == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create window.");
    }

    GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width()-sizeX)/2, (videoMode.height()-sizeY)/2);

    glfwShowWindow(window);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GL.createCapabilities();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    Texture texture = new Texture("brick.png"); //Here is the init call.

    System.out.println("texture finished loading");
```

Any idea of what it could be ?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

Strangely, the ImageIO.read() method works if I call it before creating a window with glfwCreateWindow(). It has something to do with lwjgl, not the file access.

Comment: Where is the file "brick.png" in relation to the user directory? Why are you using Files in the first place and not resources?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suppose there are other ways to load images. I'm using this one because it is pretty simple. The brick.png file is placed in the eclipse project folder (same folder as 'src'). I always did it like this and this is the first time I'm having a problem with.

Comment: @CraigR8806 SlickUtils is not supported in LWJGL anymore, since LWJGL 3

Comment: Oh geez, sorry about that... I loved that library...

Answer (score 4):

Are you running macOS?

"ImageIO initializes AWT. The problem is that the GLFW and AWT event loops cannot run at the same time in the main/first thread on macOS" http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6527.0

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out the real problem so I tried to fire the texture constructor in a lot of places. Apparently, all works fine if you call ImageIO.read() BEFORE the glfwCreateWindow() method.

So I just need to load the bufferedImage first, then create a window and finally load the texture in the GPU through usual OpenGL methods.

This is probably a release bug. I'm on LWJGL 3.1.2 build 29